# How to solve and graph that equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I'm having trouble with this task. I know that if we multiply the denominator by its conjugate, we'll get the real part there. However, I'm struggling with this particular problem, and I would like to master complex numbers well.

**z is a complex number**

Exercise: Draw the graph: $\Im \Big(\cfrac{1+iz}{1-iz}\Big) = 1 $

Comment: It might help to remember that $\operatorname{Im} w = \frac{w - \bar w}{2j}$.

Comment: Let's manipulate the expression in the parenthesis a little bit:
$$
\frac{1+iz}{1-iz} = \frac{1+iz}{1-iz} \frac{1+iz}{1+iz}
= \frac{1+2iz-z^2}{1-(iz)^2}
= \frac{1+2iz-z^2}{1+z^2}
$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: [*Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem".*](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) Please (again but more explicitely), *edit* your post to show *some* work (e.g. use the first comment above), thereby improving its [quality](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508), which at the moment is "low".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $z=x+i y, \Rightarrow \frac{1+i z}{1-i z}=\frac{1+i x-y}{1-i x+y}=\frac{(1-y)+i x}{(1+y)-i x}=\frac{((1-y)+i x)((1+y)+i x)}{(1+y)^2+x^2}$
$$
=\frac{\left(\left(1-y^2\right)-x^2\right)+i(2 x)}{(1+y)^2+x^2}
$$

So; $\Rightarrow \operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{1+i z}{1-i z}\right)=\frac{2 x}{(1+y)^2+x^2}=1, \Rightarrow(1+y)^2+x^2=2 x$

Thus; $\Rightarrow(1+y)^2+x^2-2 x+1=1$
$$
\Rightarrow(y+1)^2+(x-1)^2=1 \ldots \text { eq }(1)
$$

Since, equation of a circle with cense at $(h, k) $ is ; (and radius 1).
$$
\Rightarrow(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=1 \ldots e q(2)
$$

So, by comparing eq (1) to eq (2).
$$
\Rightarrow(h=1, k=-1)
$$

Therefore, The graph of this will be a circle at $(1,-1)$ of radius 1 So, In complex plane, the graph will also be a circle with centre at $\left(z_0=1-i\right)$ and radius 1 .

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @PawełMichoń it was my pleasure sir !

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}=\frac{i(1+iz)}{i(1-iz)}=\frac{i-z}{i+z}$$

which is easier to manipulate.

Now, let $z=x+iy$.

Thus we have $$\frac{i-x-iy}{i+x+iy}=\\\frac{-x-i(y-1)}{x+i(y+1)}
=\\\frac{[-x-i(y-1)][x-i(y+1)]}{[x+i(y+1)][x-i(y+1)]}=\\\frac{-x^2+ix(y+1)-ix(y-1)-(y-1)(y+1)}{x^2+(y+1)^2}=\\\frac{-x^2-y^2+1+2ix}{x^2+(y+1)^2}$$

Now, $\Im\Big(\frac{-x^2-y^2+1+2ix}{x^2+(y+1)^2}\Big)=1\Rightarrow$ $$x^2+(y+1)^2=2x\Rightarrow\\x^2-2x+1+(y+1)^2=1\Rightarrow\\(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=1$$
which is the circle with center at $K(1,-1)$ and radius $r=1$.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @AnneBauval Had it been against the quality standard policy, it would have already been flagged/downvoted sufficiently. Even if we assume that this "democratic" process was broken, no I do not interpret it as a question that falls under the "low-quality" standard. So, what you are saying is purely your speculative opinion...

Comment: Time will tell. At least this "opinion" relies on objective criteria, and is already not only mine.

Comment: @AnneBauval Objective criteria can be cited for the question being of sufficient quality and interest to merit its place here. As for "already not only yours"-I see 2 votes to close and a top answer with 3 upvotes. So, let's see how the mathstack.. hive mind decides.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @PawełMichoń You are welcome!